# if click on "URL Rewrite Management" create error

Tags: error, url, url-rewrite

today in my store magento if click on   "URL Rewrite Management" in backend menu create this error(this is a log)

```
eTrace:
#0 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
#1 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(640): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
#2 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1624): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
#3 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(964): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 0, NULL)
#5 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 0, NULL)
#6 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/UrlrewriteController.php(56): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(0)
#7 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/UrlrewriteController.php(68): Mage_Adminhtml_UrlrewriteController->_initRegistry()
#8 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_UrlrewriteController->indexAction()
#9 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#10 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/lecolartga/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/lecolartga/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: have you used any third party extension ??

Comment: yes, i use custom theme by themeforest, and   also used another extension that then I deleted a few days ago

Comment: You should go with @Marius suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have an attribute (product or category) that has a backend model that's not valid.

Run this query on the database to see the attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'fileattributes/attribute_backend_file';
```

If you don't need the attribute(s) that result from there, you can delete them, but backup your db first.

Answer (score 0):

You have create an eav attribute which backend module is `fileattributes/attribute_backend_file`.This Attribute may be `Dropdown` or `Multiselct`.
You need delete this attribute because it `Backend Model Class donot not exits`.that why is create issue.Just delete  from `eav_attibute` table

http://www.atwix.com/magento/frontend-backend-source/

Answer (score -1):

thanks Marius and Amit Bera , have solved

i have erase the table in database, this table is related to extension have erase some day ago.